Packer Shared source file across multiple templates
I have a few packer templates that exist in a templates/ directory, eg:
templates/
  - app1/
    - source.pkr.hcl
    - build.pkr.hcl
  - app2
    - source.pkr.hcl
    - build.pkr.hcl

There's about 7 of these appX folders, and their source.pkr.hcl are all identical.
Their documentation Shows that I can (and do) add build-specific values with:
build {
  source "source.amazon-ebs.shared" {
    ami_name = "some custom name"
  }
 ...

but that just means that I have 7 of the exact same soruce.pkr.hcl files in my repo. Is there a way to pull these source.pkr.hcl files into a single file thats referenced across all templates?
As a fun aside, I've actually tried keeping a templates/source.pkr.hcl file, with symlinks in each project directory which does the job, but that feels like a hack solution that comes with me needing to keep track of symlinks which could get tedious as the project grows.
Chat Gippety seems to think I can just call packer build template/source.pkr.hcl template/appX.pkr.hcl but as of 1.11.2 that just throws an error.
